# How can I parse AJAX Json data in object form in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

This is my JSON data **Content.json**

```
[{
    status: "Allocated",
    count: 45
}, {
    status: "Bench",
    count: 89
}, {
    status: "Mobile",
    count: 12
}, {
    status: "Project",
    count: 1
}, {
    status: "SAP",
    count: 18
}, {
    status: "Testing",
    count: 68
}, {
    status: "vvvv",
    count: 70
}];
```

**trying to fetch that JSON file**

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('valueController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

var mainInfo = null;

  $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "/JSON/Content.json",
    dataType: 'json',
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {

     $scope.mainInfo = response.data;

      $window.alert(response.data);

    }, function myError(response) 
    {
      $window.alert(response.statusText);
  });



$scope.chartOptions = {

            dataSource: mainInfo,       

            series: {
                argumentField: "status",
                valueField: "count",
                name: "SIDG Java",
                type: "bar",
                color: '#1899dd'
            }
        };

}]);
```

In alert I am getting :

Localhost:8080 says:

```
[{
    status: "Allocated",
    count: 45
}, {
    status: "Bench",
    count: 89
}, {
    status: "Mobile",
    count: 12
}, {
    status: "Project",
    count: 1
}, {
    status: "SAP",
    count: 18
}, {
    status: "Testing",
    count: 68
}, {
    status: "vvvv",
    count: 70
}];
```

And what i am expecting is

Localhost:8080 says:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
```

Comment: Show us what is inside `response.data`

Comment: [{
    status: "Allocated",
    count: 45
}, {
    status: "Bench",
    count: 89
}, {
    status: "Mobile",
    count: 12
}, {
    status: "Project",
    count: 1
}, {
    status: "SAP",
    count: 18
}, {
    status: "Testing",
    count: 68
}, {
    status: "vvvv",
    count: 70
}];

Comment: Why are you expecting multiple arrays of objects ? What are those objects ?

Comment: what do you mean when you type "but I am getting actual data"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting [object,object][object,object][object,object] in the alert by implementing your code. Please check the JSON once again.

You can parse the data by **JSON.parse(response.data)**, if you need the [object,object] structure

Comment: $window.alert(JSON.parse(response.data));

Comment: I tried  $window.alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));   which works but it is in string format .. and i am expecting object,object][object,object] format

Comment: it might be possible that there was an error, when there was no popup. please check the console once. i also got error on first time.

Comment: $window.alert(JSON.parse(response.data)); is working with below JSON
[{"status":"Allocated","count":45},{"status":"Bench","count":89}]

Make sure you give " " to attributes also..

Comment: @vikram : did you find the answer..?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that somehow AngularJS cannot detect JSON in the response data. It could be that the `Content-Type` header in the response is not `application/json`?

You can try replacing `dataType: 'json'` in your `$http` config with `responseType: 'json'` to tell AngularJS to anticipate a JSON response.

Answer (score -2):

To display in alert convert it into json string with JSON.stringify function.

Comment: This is the opposite of what the asker requested. They are expecting an array of objects, but are getting the result as a string.

Comment: please use JSON.parse